# Pandas Groupby rolling sum of multiple columns on datetime column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get a rolling sum of multiple columns by group, rolling on a datetime column (i.e. over a specified time interval). Rolling of one column seems to be working fine, but when I roll over multiple columns by vectorizing, I am getting unexpected results.

My first attempt:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"column1": range(6), 
                   "column2": range(6), 
                   'group': 3*['A','B'], 
                   'date':pd.date_range("20190101", periods=6)})

(df.groupby('group').rolling("1d", on='date')['column1'].sum()).groupby('group').shift(fill_value=0)

# output:
group  date      
A      2019-01-01    0.0
       2019-01-03    0.0
       2019-01-05    2.0
B      2019-01-02    0.0
       2019-01-04    1.0
       2019-01-06    3.0
Name: column1, dtype: float64
```

The above produced the desired results, however I lost the original index in the process. Since in my data some dates are the same, I would have to join back on the original dataframe on group+date which is inefficient. I therefore applied the following to avoid this and to keep the original index:

```
df.groupby('group').apply(lambda x: x.rolling("1d", on='date')['column1'].sum().shift(fill_value=0))

# output:
group   
A      0    0.0
       2    0.0
       4    2.0
B      1    0.0
       3    1.0
       5    3.0
Name: column1, dtype: float64
```

With this I can easily assign it to a new column of the original df by sorting on the index. Now I would like to repeat same for 'column2' and do this by vectorization. However, the result I get is unexpected:

```
df.groupby('group').apply(lambda x: x.rolling("1d", on='date')[['column1','column2']].sum().shift(fill_value=0))

# output:

   column1  column2       date
0      0.0      0.0 1970-01-01
1      0.0      0.0 1970-01-01
2      0.0      0.0 2019-01-01
3      1.0      1.0 2019-01-02
4      2.0      2.0 2019-01-03
5      3.0      3.0 2019-01-04
```

The result is correct, but unexpected for the following reasons: (1) group_keys in the groupby is ignored (2) It sorted the result automatically and reset the index like in a 'transform' method.

I would like to understand why this happened and also are there alternative ways to achieve the results above.

Answer (score 0):

I took your original approach and did some changes. Can you check if this is what you wanted?

Reset the index of the original data frame and assign the original index a column name.

```
df = df.reset_index().rename(columns={df.index.name: 'index'})
```

Now, you have the same original data frame, but it has an additional column called `index` that is the original index.

Apply the `rolling` on the `groupby` data frame grouped by `group` and `index` columns on the 2 columns `column1` and `column2`.

```
(df.groupby(['group', 'index']).rolling("1d", on='date')[['column1', 'column2']].sum()).groupby('group').shift(fill_value=0)
```

Result:

```
                        column1  column2
group index date                        
A     0     2019-01-01      0.0      0.0
      2     2019-01-03      0.0      0.0
      4     2019-01-05      2.0      2.0
B     1     2019-01-02      0.0      0.0
      3     2019-01-04      1.0      1.0
      5     2019-01-06      3.0      3.0
```

If you want the original index back, reset the multi-index and set the 'index' as index

```
(df.groupby(['group', 'index']).rolling("1d", on='date')[['column1', 'column2']].sum()).groupby('group').shift(fill_value=0).reset_index().set_index('index')
```

Result:

```
      group       date  column1  column2
index                                   
0         A 2019-01-01      0.0      0.0
2         A 2019-01-03      0.0      0.0
4         A 2019-01-05      2.0      2.0
1         B 2019-01-02      0.0      0.0
3         B 2019-01-04      1.0      1.0
5         B 2019-01-06      3.0      3.0
```

Add a `.sort_index()` if you want it sorted

```
      group       date  column1  column2
index                                   
0         A 2019-01-01      0.0      0.0
1         B 2019-01-02      0.0      0.0
2         A 2019-01-03      0.0      0.0
3         B 2019-01-04      1.0      1.0
4         A 2019-01-05      2.0      2.0
5         B 2019-01-06      3.0      3.0
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: Thanks for the taking the time to work on this. But this only works if rolling window is "1d". The moment you get to "3d" and up, result is incorrect. This is because you groupby index, which means each row gets treated as a single group.

Comment: @nrcjea001 I am getting the same results when using '1d' or '2d' or '3d' or '4d' for this sample data set.  Do you have a better example for 3 or greater days rolling window, I can try?

Comment: Try my method `(df.groupby('group').rolling("3d", on='date')['column1'].sum()).groupby('group').shift(fill_value=0)` and compare it with yours with the same data example.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have the rolling sum with shifted date or inn other words, all columns shifted but not the date.

## Explanation for the issue in your code

The `df.groupby('group').rolling("1d", on='date')['column1'].sum()` returns a MultiIndex with `group` and `date`. Without `['column1']`, it returns a DataFrame but the `date` remains a column. The `.groupby('group').shift(fill_value=0)` shifts all columns but leaves the (multi-)index and you fill the missing values with 0, i.e. 1970-01-01 for dates.

## Solution

Split things up. Do the rolling, and apply the shift to the columns of interest.

```py
# define the columns which should be shifted
columns = df.columns.difference(['date', 'group'])

# get the rolling for all columnns
df_i = df.groupby('group').rolling("1d", on='date').sum()

# do the shift only for specific columns - but not others, here the 'date' column
df_i[columns] = df_i[columns].groupby('group').shift(fill_value=0)
```

```
         column1  column2       date
group                               
A     0      0.0      0.0 2019-01-01
      2      0.0      0.0 2019-01-03
      4      2.0      2.0 2019-01-05
B     1      0.0      0.0 2019-01-02
      3      1.0      1.0 2019-01-04
      5      3.0      3.0 2019-01-06
```

**Alternative:** You could also add the `date` to the  multi-index and do the shift (probably slower, though)

```
df_i = df.groupby('group').rolling("1d", on='date').sum()
df_i.set_index([df_i.index, 'date']).groupby('group').shift(fill_value=0)
```

### Speed testing

As it seems performance is of interest, here a comparison - also the other solutions don't provide the result. Increasing the length of the DataFrame form 6 to 1e4 and testing the performance with, i.e. measuring [davidbilla](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62640058/15330539) answer:

```py
%%timeit -n 3 -r 3
df_i = df.reset_index().rename(columns={df.index.name: 'index'})
(df_i.groupby(['group', 'index']).rolling("1d", on='date')[['column1', 'column2']].sum()).groupby('group').shift(fill_value=0)
```

and OP's:

```py
%timeit -n 3 -r 3 df.groupby('group').apply(lambda x: x.rolling("1d", on='date')[['column1','column2']].sum().shift(fill_value=0))
```

| solution | time (mean ± std. dev. of 3 runs, 3 loops each) |
| --- | --- |
| davidbilla | 522 ms ± 15.3 ms per loop |
| nrcjea001 (OP) | 255 ms ± 6.25 ms per loop |
| this solution | 22.3 ms ± 2.03 ms per loop |

Answer (score 0):

It works fine.
Try this:

```py
df.groupby('group').apply(lambda x: x.set_index('date')[columns_to_roll].rolling("1d").sum().shift(fill_value=0))
```